# zuerst, zunächst: difference?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, difference

I am really not catching the difference between the two.

For *zuerst* I found the definition of "(als Erstes) vor allen anderen Tätigkeiten".
For *zunächst*: "als Erstes"

I have a feeling that the difference lies in the contexts in which they are used, but I don't see it. For instance, following the above definitions, (to me) the adverbs can be exchanged without any change of meaning in the following example:

> Ich möchte mir zuerst/zunächst die Hände waschen.

To reiterate, **my question is whether there is a change of register, of context or of what between the two.**

Comment: Zunächst sounds more formal. It has kind of a mythical / negative swing to use it. "Zunächst setzten wir uns alle mal hin" >> implies something shoking may follow, or there is a tension between the listeners. "Füllen sie zunächst das Feld x aus" would be something formal on a web page, but not used in common language. Also, I believe that a non-native speaker would never get the difference anyway, so use either of the two words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a native German I've never really thought about this word until now but when reading your question, I was curious how *zunächst* can mean the same thing as *zuerst* while *als nächstes* is distinct to *als erstes*.

*Als erstes* = First of all
*Als nächstes* = Next (Second, third, fourth thing,... but never first thing)

But:
*Zuerst* = *Zunächst* = At first

I can't really answer how this distinction evolved (a quick Google search only gave a few hints but that's not enough for a conclusive answer), but with respect to your actual question it might help to look at it like this:

*Erst* means *first* and so you can interpret *zuerst* as *the first thing*.
While *nächst* can mean *next*, you need to know that *nächst* is derived from the superlative of *nah* (*near*, *close*). Hence, you can interpret *zunächst* as *the closest/nearest thing*.

You can see this meaning more clearly in its prepositional meaning where you cannot replace it with *zuerst*. [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zun%C3%A4chst) defines it as *unmittelbar neben* or *in nächster Nähe von*. Example given there:

> das Gebäude zunächst der Universität ist die Universitätsbibliothek

Meaning, the nearest building to the university is the university library.

Concluding, there's not much of a difference between *zuerst* and *zunächst* as an adverb; it doesn't matter if you talk about the first thing or the closest/nearest thing. It's the same thing after all.

A few further notes:
In the Grimmsche Wörterbuch they say [*zunächst* takes *zuerst* as a "role model"](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/cgi-bin/WBNetz/wbgui_py?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GZ10211#XGZ10211):

> nach dem vorbild von zuerst

I couldn't make out the oldest citations, but *zunächst* seem to be in common usage since the 16th century.

Several dictionaries (like DWDS, follow the link above) separate the adverb *zunächst* into two similar meanings. The first is synonym to *zuerst*, the other synonym to *vorerst*, *vorläufig*. Here's an example from DWDS:

> dieses Problem wollen wir zunächst ausklammern

I do think that you can replace it with *zuerst* but you arguably change the meaning slightly. The proper translation into English for this example might be "for now", "for the time being". That is, "(at) the present time" or "for a short period of time but not permanently".

DWDS also lists [several meanings for *zuerst*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zuerst). Unfortunately the definitions are not very clear to me and examples are missing, but 1b is clearly a case where you cannot use *zunächst*. Here's an example of my own:

> Er ist zuerst[=als Erstes] ins Ziel gekommen.

In this context, you cannot use *zunächst*.

Comment: *dieses Problem wollen wir zunächst ausklammern* & *I do think that you can replace it with zuerst* - - no, not really; probably you mixed it up with a quite similar word: **vorerst**

Comment: @VolkerLandgraf If I meant "vorerst" I wouldn't have continued with "it changes the meaning slightly" because "vorerst" and "zunächst" have the very same meaning. You can indeed replace it with "zuerst" but then it becomes "In a first step, we exclude this problem" which is in contrast to "vorerst" / "zunächst" where it's translated as "For now, we exclude this problem". But then again, what's the difference between "in a first step" and "for now" from a semantical point of view?

Comment: Besides, I mention "vorerst" just in the paragraph where I lead over to the example.

Comment: @Em1 In English, AFAIK one would only say "first" or "in a first step" if he/she is enumerating the steps to be taken (e.g. "first, we'll take him to the hospital, then we'll call his family"). If there is an action which must be done now and later you will consider if something else must be done, "for now" or "for the time being" would be used (e.g. "for now, we'll take him to the hospital and make sure he's ok"). So I see a semantic difference between both.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a difference in your example because of the semantics of that specific example.

> zuerst — at first
>
> zunächst — as the next step

When there's a sequence of steps, the difference becomes clear.

> Zunächst schneidet man das Gemüse klein. — HALT! **Zuerst** muss man das Gemüse natürlich schälen.

It must be *zuerst* in that example, to express it's the very first step.

Comment: Which shows that *zunächst* can connotates an aspect of desire, potential or expectation, whereas *zuerst* is what, imperative?

Comment: I'm afraid but I think that you can swap "zunächst" and "zuerst" in your example. Both words are defined as "the first thing of all". That's why the question came up in the first place.

Comment: @em1 I disagree, you can't swap them here. Well it stays understandable from context but is quite a lot sloppier if you do. If you use *zuerst* first, a later *zunächst* doesn't mean *before that*, you would have to use something like *vorher*.

Answer (score 1):

Acc. to [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/zuerst), zuerst has additional meanings to those of zunächst.

> 1. b) als Erster, Erste, Erstes
>      er ist mit dem Kopf zuerst (voraus) ins Wasser gesprungen

=

> he jumped into the water head first

In contrast,

> er ist mit dem Kopf zunächst ins Wasser gesprungen

would mean

> at first, he jumped into the water

Comment: More importantly, "zuerst / als erster die Hände waschen" can imply *as the first of all subjects in the context*.

Answer (score 0):

Zuerst: Ich wasche mir zuerst die Hände und dann das Gesicht.
Zunächst: Zunächst wasche ich mir die Hände und dann das Gesicht.

Zuerst ist die erste Handlung in einer bestimmten Reihenfolge.
Zunächst ist die nächste Handlung in einer Reihe von Handlungen.

Beides bezieht sich auf Handlungen, nicht auf Dinge.

Comment: Bitte nicht mehrere Antworten zu einer Frage posten - es gibt eine Editierfunktion, mit der man  Antworten bearbeiten kann, falls man nachträglich etwas ergänzen will.

Comment: Außerdem ist es hier üblich, in der Sprache zu antworten, in der die Frage gestellt wurde.

Answer (score 0):

Zunächst wird auch gerne in Artikeln benutzt: "Zunächst war die Unfallursache unklar."

Diese Benutzung ist falsch, denn "zunächst" sagt aus, dass es später dann geklärt war. Der Autor will aber sagen: "Bisher war die Unfallursache unklar." Denn die Unfallursache wird ermittelt und steht zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt fest. Der Autor wollte aber ausdrücken, dass ihm zum Zeitpunkt des Schreibens des Artikels die Unfallursache nicht klar war. (Oder der Polizei ...)

Er würde also schreiben müssen:
Zunächst war die Unfallursache unklar, konnte dann aber ermittelt werden...

Oder:
Bisher ist die Unfallursache unklar, wird aber sicherlich zu einem späteren Zeitpunkt ermittelt.